# linker (ld) on OS X: How to use -Wl,--start-group (and --end-group)?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, ld

I am building some projects externally which use libclang static libs.

Linking fails like this:

```
ld: unknown option: --start-group
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The reason I need to use this is because of circular dependencies (or as it turns out, I guess because of not knowing the correct library order).

So far I have to resort to taking the `-Wl,--{start,end}-group` out of the makefile, looking at the undefined symbols error list, finding the libs that have them with `nm`, and appending them manually to the library list (so they appear more than once in the library list).

Comment: Are you asking why your `ld` implementation does not accept `--start-group`? Or what?

Comment: Well it clearly doesn't support it (manpage doesnt mention, etc) so i'm looking for a better way to get it compiling without hacks. For example an alternative linker implementation. Can't use gold though since it's ELF only.

Comment: Okay well that's clearer; perhaps you could clarify it in your question a bit? Anyway, I can at least corroborate your findings that [Mac OSX's `ld` implementation doesn't support `--start-group`](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-commit/2010-January/016609.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct order of LLVM/Clang libs (taken from my own project that uses it) for 3.5 is:

```
    "clangFrontend",
    "clangSerialization",
    "clangDriver",
    "clangTooling",
    "clangCodeGen",
    "clangParse",
    "clangSema",
    "clangAnalysis",
    "clangRewriteFrontend",
    "clangRewrite",
    "clangEdit",
    "clangAST",
    "clangLex",
    "clangBasic",
    "LLVMLTO",
    "LLVMObjCARCOpts",
    "LLVMLinker",
    "LLVMipo",
    "LLVMVectorize",
    "LLVMBitWriter",
    "LLVMIRReader",
    "LLVMAsmParser",
    "LLVMR600CodeGen",
    "LLVMR600Desc",
    "LLVMR600Info",
    "LLVMR600AsmPrinter",
    "LLVMSystemZDisassembler",
    "LLVMSystemZCodeGen",
    "LLVMSystemZAsmParser",
    "LLVMSystemZDesc",
    "LLVMSystemZInfo",
    "LLVMSystemZAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMHexagonCodeGen",
    "LLVMHexagonAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMHexagonDesc",
    "LLVMHexagonInfo",
    "LLVMNVPTXCodeGen",
    "LLVMNVPTXDesc",
    "LLVMNVPTXInfo",
    "LLVMNVPTXAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMCppBackendCodeGen",
    "LLVMCppBackendInfo",
    "LLVMMSP430CodeGen",
    "LLVMMSP430Desc",
    "LLVMMSP430Info",
    "LLVMMSP430AsmPrinter",
    "LLVMXCoreDisassembler",
    "LLVMXCoreCodeGen",
    "LLVMXCoreDesc",
    "LLVMXCoreInfo",
    "LLVMXCoreAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMMipsDisassembler",
    "LLVMMipsCodeGen",
    "LLVMMipsAsmParser",
    "LLVMMipsDesc",
    "LLVMMipsInfo",
    "LLVMMipsAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMAArch64Disassembler",
    "LLVMAArch64CodeGen",
    "LLVMAArch64AsmParser",
    "LLVMAArch64Desc",
    "LLVMAArch64Info",
    "LLVMAArch64AsmPrinter",
    "LLVMAArch64Utils",
    "LLVMARMDisassembler",
    "LLVMARMCodeGen",
    "LLVMARMAsmParser",
    "LLVMARMDesc",
    "LLVMARMInfo",
    "LLVMARMAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMPowerPCDisassembler",
    "LLVMPowerPCCodeGen",
    "LLVMPowerPCAsmParser",
    "LLVMPowerPCDesc",
    "LLVMPowerPCInfo",
    "LLVMPowerPCAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMSparcDisassembler",
    "LLVMSparcCodeGen",
    "LLVMSparcAsmParser",
    "LLVMSparcDesc",
    "LLVMSparcInfo",
    "LLVMSparcAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMTableGen",
    "LLVMDebugInfo",
    "LLVMOption",
    "LLVMX86Disassembler",
    "LLVMX86AsmParser",
    "LLVMX86CodeGen",
    "LLVMSelectionDAG",
    "LLVMAsmPrinter",
    "LLVMX86Desc",
    "LLVMX86Info",
    "LLVMX86AsmPrinter",
    "LLVMX86Utils",
    "LLVMJIT",
    "LLVMLineEditor",
    "LLVMMCAnalysis",
    "LLVMMCDisassembler",
    "LLVMInstrumentation",
    "LLVMInterpreter",
    "LLVMCodeGen",
    "LLVMScalarOpts",
    "LLVMInstCombine",
    "LLVMTransformUtils",
    "LLVMipa",
    "LLVMAnalysis",
    "LLVMProfileData",
    "LLVMMCJIT",
    "LLVMTarget",
    "LLVMRuntimeDyld",
    "LLVMObject",
    "LLVMMCParser",
    "LLVMBitReader",
    "LLVMExecutionEngine",
    "LLVMMC",
    "LLVMCore",
    "LLVMSupport"
```

You don't have to determine the order yourself- use -llvm-config to get the LLVM order. The Clang order is a bit trickier- from memory, you need to extract it from makefiles used to build Clang itself, or something like that. However, the Clang list is pretty small so determining it is pretty easy given the LLVM order and that Clang must go before LLVM. I don't know where libclang goes in this list since I don't use it, but I'm guessing that it should go first.

Comment: Excuse me, how you extract the linking order from makefiles?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @Puppy does answer the OP's ultimate need -- how to get the libraries in required link order.

But it does not answer the OP's actual question -- how to use `--start-group` and `--end-group`.

The `clang` and `gcc` command line options are:

```
-Wl,--start-group
libs-in-the-order-you-need ...
-Wl,--end-group
```

Your mileage may vary on other compilers.

UPDATE (2019.07.11):
David Given points out that the gcc provided by default on OSX doesn't even support these options.

That is because OSX only provides `gcc 2.x` compatibility.
I was using `gcc 4.8` and `gcc 7.0` when I started using these options in my project.
I am not sure when they were first added to gcc.

Comment: `--start-group` and `--end-group` are not supported by the OSX, so this doesn't work for them.

Comment: OSX provides a `gcc 2.x` compatiblity. For some reason they don't bother to update to the latest gcc capabilities.  So, is also depends on which _version_ of gcc you use. I was using `gcc 4.8`.

Comment: `--start-group` is a linker option.  The question was specifically how to use that flag on macOS, and the answer is to install GNU ld.